# Behavior of foreach when setting new chars in a String

Tags: java, string, for-loop, foreach, char

I just read a question about chars and I had a doubt about it so I started to try some code... I'm trying to set all chars from a String one by one using a loop, I've tried with for and the "forEach" version of it, these are my tests:

```
String testString = "testing";
char[] array = testingString.toCharArray();
```

Then the loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = 'x';
}
```

And this is the output for that loop: (the **expected** one)

```
"xxxxxxx"
```

But then I've tried with the another "for" format:

```
for(char c: array) {
    c = 'x';
}
```

And it didn't work for me.. the output was the same String ("testing"). I'm misunderstanding the behavior of the for each? Why is the 2nd loop not working the same as the first one? I've used that loop format a lot of times but I can't understand why is not working in this case. I'm not familiar with the char type, maybe I'm missing something about it.

Comment: Why did you expect variable `c` of type `char` to be a pointer to the array cell value?

Comment: I thought that was how the for works, I mean.. "for each char in this array set it to 'x' " (using 'c' as a pointer to that char inside the array)

Comment: `char c` does not declare a pointer. It declares a variable of the *primitive* type `char` for holding the value. `for(char c: array)` means "for each *value* `c` in the array". It doesn't mean "for each array item as pointed to by `c`".

Comment: Ok, I got it, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in JLS [§14.14.2. The enhanced `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), the following loop:

```
for(char c: array) {
    c = 'x';
}
```

is equivalent to the following basic `for` statement:

```
for (int #i = 0; #i < array.length; #i++) {
    char c = array[#i];
    c = 'x';
}
```

As you can see, changing `c` will not affect the array.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are edditing the character, not the corresponding charAt the inception String.
Probably, you should take the position of these char at the string and setting it up.